# Migration from SpringBoot 2.7 to SpringBoot 3.1 : issue with NamedStoredProcedureQuery

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data

I have a @NamedStoredProcedureQuery (DB2) defined in an jpa entity like this :

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
    name = "MY_PROCEDURE",
    procedureName = "MY_SCHEMA.MY_PROCEDURE", 
    parameters = {@StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "COMPANY", type = String.class)}
)
public class MyEntity{
...
}
```

Then I have a repository class with one method

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, MyEntityId> {
    @Procedure(name = "MY_PROCEDURE")
    Map<String, String> getData(@Param("COMPANY") String company);
}
```

With SpringBoot 2.7 it was OK, when I try to getData but not with SpringBoot 3.1

I have this error, it seems that the @Param COMPANY is no longer recognized

> [SQL0312] Variable COMPANY not defined or not usable

Edit : I found this doc in hibernate migration guide : https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6.0/migration-guide.adoc#procedurecall--storedprocedurequery-parameters

> For parameters defined on a ProcedureCall as accepting binding (IN and INOUT), a distinction is now made between whether setParameter is called or not. If setParameter was called, whatever value was set by the user is passed to the database. If it was not called, Hibernate will not set any value which triggers the default value defined on the database procedure argument be used